# Logo problem put in frame -CSS

Tags: css

I'm working on one site and I need frame like on http://www.thearchitecturestudio.net/.
How to put my logo(picture) like this ,overlap border ?

Answer (score 1):

that is flash but if you want to do that with html try [legend](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_legend.asp) tag.

Comment: The legend tag needs a fieldset tag, and the fieldset tag is for forms. So the real correct answer to this question is: 
Learn HTML and CSS and you will find thousand ways to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, for example:

HTML:

```
<div class="logo">
    <img src="logo.jpg">
</div>
<div class="box">
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.logo {position:absolute;border:5px solid #fff;top:0;left:10px;}
.box {border:1px solid #000;width:500px;height:400px;}
```